# Plotting multiple circles

Tags: matlab, plot, geometry, figure, centroid

I would like to plot multiple circles with the centres as centroids already determined previously.

So I have this code which uses the centroids as the centres of the circles, but I get the error: **"Error using  +  Matrix dimensions must agree."**

```
r = 4;
cen_x = centroid(:,1);
cen_y = centroid(:,2);
th = 0:pi/50:2*pi;
xunit = r * cos(th) + cen_x;
yunit = r * sin(th) + cen_y;
hold on
h = plot(xunit, yunit);
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add `cos(th)` and `cen_x` together and their dimensions don't match up. You will need to use `bsxfun` so that the dimensions are properly broadcasted.

```
xunit = bsxfun(@plus, cen_x, r * cos(th)).';   
yunit = bsxfun(@plus, cen_y, r * sin(th)).';

plot(xunit, yunit)
```

You could also use `rectangle` to draw your circles for you. You can also specify a `FaceColor` to fill them in.

```
positions = [centroid - (r/2), r + zeros(size(centroid))];

for k = 1:size(positions, 1)
    rectangle('Position', positions(k,:), 'Curvature', [1 1], 'FaceColor', 'r');
end
```

Comment: Nicely done. I am curious whether you can then use the `imfill` function to fill these circles?